# how to explode an url in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to remove "/first" string and remove _1_1_1 at the end of the url.

```
/foo/blah/tree/first/image_pack-1-1-1
```

what i need to turn  is

```
/foo/blah/tree/image_pack
```

Here's what I have done but doesn't work as i wish. I'm stuck at some point.

```
var fileUrl = "/foo/blah/tree/first/image_pack-1-1-1";
var output = fileUrl.split(/[/ ]+/).pop();
var explode = output.split("-");
console.log(explode[0]);
```

Comment: Seriously, its just `fileUrl.split('-')[0]`...

Comment: No, it's not. Read the question again.

Comment: is /first/ a constant? will it ever be /second/?

Comment: Will `/first` and `-1-1-1` always be the same?

Comment: @Andy fine, it's just `fileUrl.split('-')[0].replace('first/','')`

Comment: @somethinghere come on now. No fighting.

Comment: @evolutionbox Yes, that comment was a bit snarky. Adjusted it just as you posted it.

Comment: @somethinghere no problem. =) Also, `fileUrl.split('-')[0].replace('first/','')` should definitely work, unless `first/` changes...

Comment: thanks somethinghere, its a url, first value will not be same on every url. is there any other way ?

Comment: why don't you just `fileUrl.replace("/first", "").replace("-1-1-1", "")` or `fileURL.replace(/\/first|-1-1-1/g, "")`?

Comment: values changes and will not be same but their place will be always stay same @DanielCheung

Comment: I'm not sure of it. OP ought to give more examples

Comment: Why not `fileUrl.replace(/^([\w\/]*)\/\w+(\/\w+)(?:-[\d\-]*)?$/, '$1$2')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you can realistically get there in one line. How about this. It splits against the first dash, splits the first element against the backslashes, and then splices that 4th element right out regardless of what it's called. Then just join it back together.

```
var output = fileUrl.split('-')[0].split('/');
output.splice(4, 1);
output = output.join('/'); // /foo/blah/tree/image_pack
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tueu7az3/)

Comment: thank you so much @Andy, This worked out of box. Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

The question on everyone's mind is: how recurring is this? Is `first` a variable? Is `1-1-1-1` always at the end? If both of them are constant, then it's easy:

```
fileUrl.split('-')[0].replace('first/','')
```

But otherwise, you might be better off constructing a function for it:

```
function fileUrl(url, replacements){
    // Allow for replacements to be empty
    replacements = replacements || [];
    // Split at the `-` - a more versatile way would be too complex here.
    url = url.split('-')[0];
    for(var i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++){
        url = url.replace(replacements[i], '');
    }
    // Remove any double slashes that have accumulated
    while(url.indexOf('//').length >= 0) url.replace('//','/');
    return url;
}
```

Now you can easily do this:

```
fileUrl('/foo/blah/tree/first/image_pack-1-1-1', ['first']);
```

```js
function fileUrl(url, replacements){
        replacements = replacements || [];
        url = url.split('-')[0];
        for(var i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++){
            url = url.replace(replacements[i], '');
        }
        while(url.indexOf('//').length >= 0) url.replace('//','/');
        return url;
    }

document.write(fileUrl('/foo/blah/tree/first/image_pack-1-1-1', ['first']));
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but first changes all the time, and the -1-1-1 number is changing but their place is always same. @somethinghere

Comment: @Profstyle which is why I wrote you a function to allows `first` to change all the time. Just fill in the correct string and it will remove _anything_ you want to remove.

Comment: thanks @somethinghere but Andy's solution worked better for me, Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

would something like this work?

```js
var fileUrl = "/foo/blah/tree/SOMERANDOMTHINGREMOVEDHERE/image_pack-1-1-1";
var newUrl1 = fileUrl.split('-')[0].split('/');
console.log(newUrl1);
var finalUrl = '';
for(var i = 0; i < newUrl1.length; i++) {
    if (i != 4) {
        finalUrl += newUrl1[i] + '/';
    }
}
alert(finalUrl);
```